# Backup with Hanoi Strategy

Tags: bash, file-system

I want your suggestions about this shell script. I use it to backup some configurations on my home media server.

What improvements would you do? Keep in mind, I want to optimize space and speed and at the same time, backup the maximum configurations over time.

p.-s. For more informations about the hanoi scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme.

**ideas :**

- Only use the hanoi scheme when the limit space is reach by checking the space required by rsync.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ==================================================================================
# Description:  BackUp script following a Hanoi scheme using rsync.
# Author:       Hugo Lapointe Di Giacomo
# ==================================================================================

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
#set -o xtrace

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Options
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setsMax=16 # ................................ Maximum number of sets bakcup.
cmdPrefix="" # .............................. "echo" if dry-run enable, "" otherwise.
srcDir="/appdata" # ......................... Source directory to backup.
dstDir="/mnt/backup/snapshots" # ............ Destination directory to backup in.
logDir="/mnt/backup/logs" # ................. Logs directory.


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Constants
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEC_PER_DAY=86400; # ........................ Number of seconds per day.
LATEST_SNAP="$dstDir/latest"; # ............. The "latest" snap.
LATEST_LOG="$logDir/latest"; # .............. The "latest" log.
DATE_FORMAT="%Y-%m-%d"; # ................... The format of a date.
HOUR_FORMAT="%H:%M"; # ...................... The format of a hour.


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Show usage of this script.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function showUsage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [OPTIONS]..."
    echo ""
    echo "Options available:"
    echo " -h, --help   Show usage of the script."
    echo " -m, --max    Maximum sets of backup."
    echo " -s, --src    Source directory to backup."
    echo " -d. --dst    Destination directory to backup in."
    echo " -l, --log    Log directory."
    echo " -r, --dry    Enable dry-run."
}


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parse arguments.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function parseArgs() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case $1 in
            -h|--help)
                showUsage $@
                exit 0
            ;;

            -m|--max)
                setsMax=${2:-$setsMax}
                shift 2
            ;;

            -s|--src)
                if [ -d "$2" ]; then
                    srcDir="$2"
                fi
                shift 2
            ;;

            -d|--dst)
                if [ -d "$2" ]; then
                    dstDir="$2"
                fi
                shift 2
            ;;

            -l|--log)
                if [ -d "$2" ]; then
                    logDir="$2"
                fi
                shift 2
            ;;

            -r|--dry)
                cmdPrefix="echo"
                shift 1
            ;;

            *)
                echo "Unknown option or value: $1"
                showUsage $@
                exit 1
            ;;
        esac
    done
}


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create a backup with rsync.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function createBackUp() {   
    snapDir="$dstDir/$1" # ................. Name of the snap dir.
    logFile="$logDir/$1.log" # ............. Name of the log file.

    RSYNC_CMD="rsync " # ................... Rsync Command.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--archive " # .............. Enable recursion and preserve infos.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--verbose " # .............. Increase amount of infos printed.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--human-readable " # ....... Output number in readable format.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--progress " # ............. Show progress during transfer.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--delete " # ............... Delete files from receiving side.
    RSYNC_CMD+="--link-dest=$LATEST_SNAP " # "latest" symbolic link to hardlink.
    RSYNC_CMD+="$srcDir " # ................ Source directory to backup.
    RSYNC_CMD+="$snapDir " # ............... Destination directory to backup in.

    # Create backup and save the output in a log file.
    $cmdPrefix $RSYNC_CMD 2>&1 | tee "$logFile"
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Update the latest links.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function updateLatestLinks() {
    $cmdPrefix rm -f "$LATEST_SNAP"
    $cmdPrefix ln -s "$snapDir" "$LATEST_SNAP"

    $cmdPrefix rm -f "$LATEST_LOG"
    $cmdPrefix ln -s "$logFile" "$LATEST_LOG"
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate the previous move in the cycle.
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function calculateDaysFromBackupOfSameSet() {
    local todayInSec=$(date +%s)
    local todayInDay=$(($todayInSec / $SEC_PER_DAY))
    
    local daysToBackup=$((2 ** ($setsMax - 1))) 

    local daysElapsed=0
    local i=1

    while [ $i -lt $(($daysToBackup / 2)) ]; do
        local rotation=$(($todayInDay & $i))
        
        if [ $rotation -eq 0 ]; then
            daysElapsed=$(($i * 2))
            break
        fi

        daysElapsed=$(($daysToBackup / 2))
        i=$((2 * $i))
    done
    
    echo $daysElapsed
}


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main function.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function main() {
    parseArgs $@
    
    local todayDatetime=$(date +$DATE_FORMAT.$HOUR_FORMAT)

    if createBackUp $todayDatetime; then
        updateLatestLinks
        
        local daysElapsed=$(calculateDaysFromBackupOfSameSet)
        local expiredDay=$(date -d "$daysElapsed days ago" +$DATE_FORMAT)
        $cmdPrefix rm -frv "$dstDir/$expiredDay."*
    fi
}

main $@
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Zeta, understood.

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edits. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: You may want to read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-post-a-follow-up-question as well.

Answer (score 10):

**Do not silently ignore invalid arguments**

Your script allows to specify the source directory (and other locations). Here is the relevant part in `function parseArgs()`:

```
            -s|--src)
                if [ -d "$2" ]; then
                    srcDir="$2"
                fi
                shift 2
            ;;
```

If `--src <sourceDir>` is specified with an invalid source directory then this argument is (silently) ignored. The consequence is that even a simple typo

```
backup --src /my_importatn_data
```

causes the default directory to be backed up, and not `/my_important_data`.

Wrong arguments (here: an invalid or not existing directory) should print an error message (to the standard error) and terminate the shell script (with a non-zero exit code).

Answer (score 8):

#### Double-quote variables used as command arguments

Although in many places in the posted code the variables used as command arguments are correctly double-quoted, there are more than a few exceptions, for example `parseArgs $@`, which should be `parseArgs "$@"` to preserve arguments with spaces.

It's a good habit to [systematically double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) used as command arguments.

#### Collect argument lists in arrays instead of strings

The `createBackUp` function collects arguments for the rsync command in a string and executes it. This will not work if some elements (here `$srcDir`, `$snapDir`, or `$LATEST_SNAP`) contain spaces.

You can make it safe by using an array instead:

```
createBackUp() {   
    snapDir="$dstDir/$1" # ................. Name of the snap dir.
    logFile="$logDir/$1.log" # ............. Name of the log file.

    RSYNC_CMD=("rsync") # ................... Rsync Command.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--archive") # .............. Enable recursion and preserve infos.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--verbose") # .............. Increase amount of infos printed.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--human-readable") # ....... Output number in readable format.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--progress") # ............. Show progress during transfer.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--delete") # ............... Delete files from receiving side.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("--link-dest=$LATEST_SNAP") # "latest" symbolic link to hardlink.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("$srcDir") # ................ Source directory to backup.
    RSYNC_CMD+=("$snapDir") # ............... Destination directory to backup in.

    # Create backup and save the output in a log file.
    $cmdPrefix "${RSYNC_CMD[@]}" 2>&1 | tee "$logFile"
}
```

I also dropped the `function` keyword which is not recommended in Bash.

#### Simplify using arithmetic context

The `calculateDaysFromBackupOfSameSet` uses several arithmetic operations and conditions which could be simplified and made more readable using *arithmetic context*:

```
calculateDaysFromBackupOfSameSet() {
    local i todayInDay daysToBackup
    local todayInSec=$(date +%s)

    ((todayInDay = todayInSec / SEC_PER_DAY))
    ((daysToBackup = 2 ** (setsMax - 2)))
    local daysElapsed=daysToBackup

    for ((i = 1; i < daysToBackup; i *= 2)); do
        if ! ((todayInDay & i)); then
            ((daysElapsed = i * 2))
            break
        fi
    done

    echo "$daysElapsed"
}
```

I also eliminated some repeated `daysToBackup / 2`.
I believe this is equivalent to the original, but I haven't tested it.
Excuse me if I made an error, the point is more to demonstrate the power of the arithmetic context.